# The button does nothing on click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am learning jquery and i am stuck with a problem.
 **Here is the code**

```
$(function(){
  var gotProducts=new Array();
  var productsWithDelete=new Array();
  $('.addProducts').on('keyup',function(event) {
    var searchVal=$(this).val().trim();
    if(searchVal.length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/url',
        data: { products: $(this).val(), },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#printTheProducts').html(msg);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $('.productsButton').click(function() {
    alert('yes');
  });

});
```

The response I am getting from the ajax call is a **button** having **class productsButton**.
Now when i try to click that button I got through ajax then it does not **alert yes**. I mean it does nothing.
**Question:-**
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try event delegation using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for generated button, As they are generated dynamically

```
$('#printTheProducts').on('click','.productsButton',function(){
    alert('yes');
});
```

Where `#printTheProducts` is the closest parent element, you can use `document` or `document.body` also as a selector!

*Syntax:*

```
$(closestparentelement).on('event','targetselector',function(){
});
```

Comment: Try jQuery live() Method.

Comment: live is deprecated so no

Comment: @Muthu FYI: `.live()` is deprecated and doesn't support the chaining of selectors!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you :) I was frustrated since last 7 hours because of this. thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome dude! Cheers! Merry X'mas :)